# Transferring shapefile to Garmin Monterra with labels/attributes

Tags: kml, gps, garmin

I would like to transfer a shapefile to my Garmin Monterra, but preserve at least one field of attributes.  So far, I have tried converting to kml, but when I load into basecamp, there are no attribute data and the waypoints are all given generic numbers.  Is there a way to export shapefiles from ArcMap so that the loaded point data in basecamp can be labeled according to an original field of attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this site:  https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=067d6ab392b24497b8466eb8447ea7eb

Download the tool - Features to GPX

Export your data as GPX and load that onto your Garmin.  The attributes will now be included in the GPX file and should be accessible from basecamp.  According to the tool info, the output is supported by basecamp.

Comment: Thanks jbalk.  The output .gpx file was not originally compatible with Basecamp.  I took an extra step and converted it into a KML and then it loaded into Basecamp fine.